# Input an Integer and get its prime factors and duplicates

Tags: c#, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prime Factors In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872962/prime-factors-in-c-sharp)

I am trying to get this coding to give me all the prime factors of the integer that is inputted, including its duplicates. I have this current code and it seems to be working sort of but it isn't showing all of it's prime factors and duplicates. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _1_Numeric_Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myInput;
            int myInt;
            int p;

            Console.WriteLine(("Please input an integer"));

            myInput = Console.ReadLine();
            myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);

            {
                for (int i = 2; i > 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 100000)

                        break;

                    if (myInt % i == 0)
                    {

                        if (i <= 3)
                        {

                            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            continue;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            for (p = 2; p < i; p++)
                                if (i % p != 0)
                                {
                                    Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                                    Console.ReadLine();
                                    return;
                                    Console.ReadLine();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    p++;
                                    continue;
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your sample so it does no mix reading/writing with computing results. And possibly remove input altogether as it is unrelated to the question. And add actual question ...

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the following code:

```
for (p = 2; p < i; p++) {
    if (i % p != 0) {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
        Console.ReadLine();
    } else {
        p++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

With this instead:

```
bool isPrime = true;

for (p = 2; p <= Math.Sqrt(i); p++) {
    if (i % p == 0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
    }

    if (isPrime) {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make a for loop like this?

```
for (int i = 2; i < myInt; i++)
{
    if(myInt % i == 0)
        //Do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm for integer factorization using trial division tries each potential factor starting from 2, and if it divides *n*, outputs the factor, reduces *n*, and searches for the next factor; note that *f* is not incremented if it divides *n*, since it might again divide the reduced *n*. The loop stops when *f* is greater than the square root of *n*, since at that point *n* must be prime. Here's the pseudocode:

```
function factors(n)
    f := 2
    while f * f <= n
        if n % f == 0
            output f
            n := n / f
        else
            f := f + 1
    output n
```

There are better ways to factor integers, but that should get you started. When you're ready for more, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) on my blog.