# Divide by prime with modulo 0

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the number 3294830924.

I want to divide it by prime numbers, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, etc..

And I want to know which operations gives me modulo 0.

something like:

```
int[] primeNumbers = ...;
var n = 3294830924;
return primeNumbers.Where(pn=> pn < n).Where(pn=> n % pn == 0)
```

is there any built in function or method to get the list of prime numbers in C# or a way to calculate this in a mathematical fashion?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers

Comment: i don't want to generate prime numbers.... but that post give me some light on where to find a prime list :)

Comment: If what you search is a prime number list, check here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/prime-number-lists.html or even http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php

Comment: *is there any built in function or method to get the list of prime numbers in C#* If you don't want to generate prime numbers, that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a `bool IsPrime(int)` or a `int[] Math.Primes`

Comment: for example, a function like IsPrime with known of primers beforehand with a hash and some clever manipulation will fit in a framework and I can't find it :D

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743192/check-if-number-is-prime-number) for one.

Comment: Given this sounds like it is just finding prime factors it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872962/prime-factors-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You could download, generate or connect to a database with a list of prime numbers and use this list every time you need to do the operation.

For example a list of the first 10,000 primes:

https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt

and first 50 million primes:

https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/

If these numbers were in a table in a relational database (such as SQL Server Express) then you could use linq to check if the number is prime more efficiently as you can have a clustered index for the prime number.

Comment: perfect, I don't want to have all so I will have some and then i will generate for bigger numbers. thanks!

Comment: I would probably not worry about the space as 1 million primes (in integers) would only use ~4mb, it is the searching which could take some time (although much less than generating the primes).

However searching for an element in a table over an index of a few million rows will complete in virtually no time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to check Prime ,

```
private bool IsPrime(int number)
{
if (number < 2) return false;
if (number == 2) return true;
if (number % 2 == 0) return false;
for (int i = 3; i * i <= number; i += 2)
if (number % i == 0) return false;
return true;
}
```

Then calculate the primes as

```
var primes =
from number in Enumerable.Range(1, your_number)
where IsPrime(number)
select number;
```

Comment: great, I will use a combination of this and a known list of prime numbers. thank you.