# is there a function to determine if prime number exists in the sum?

Tags: c#, prime-factoring

i have constants that represents a prime number. for example,

```
  enum Signals : long
    {
        LONGPULLBACK = 2,
        SHORTPULLBACK = 3,
        RSIOVERSOLD = 5,
        RSIOVERBOUGHT = 7,
        BOUGHTSIGNAL = 9,
        DOUBLEBOUGHTSIGNAL = 11,
        SOLDSIGNAL = 13,
        DOUBLESOLDSIGNAL = 17,
        MATRENDINGLONG = 19,
        MATRADENINGSHORT = 23


    }
```

for every signal triggered, i just add it to the sum. there will always be only 1 signal of each type triggered.
when i have a sum of 25, is there a function to return the prime number parts of the sum ie 2,23?

Comment: You should use a [Flags Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-5.0) for this, not prime numbers.

Comment: The decomposition of a number in prime factors (multiplication) is unique, but not the decomposition into prime summands. E.g. 20 may be 17+3 or 13+7. For a sum, use numbers of the form 2 ^ n. (Also: 9 is not prime...)

Comment: There cannot be, because for example 5+7=3+9, 2+3=5, etc

Comment: This question makes no sense. First, sums aren't prime-factorable in the first place (see previous comment). But also, _your enum values aren't even all primes_! `BOUGHTSIGNAL = 9`. Why are you using primes here instead of powers of two (i.e. `[Flags]` enum)?

Comment: What is the expected result for 24?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a comment about your original attempt, and how that could be made to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you *can* achieve what you want by using flags. Just don't use 0 as one of your flags for one of the values in your list. 0 can only denote None because you'll never be able to check whether a 0 was added. And the values must be powers of 2. So: 1, 2, 4, 8, ... And only up to 63 values (besides the 0) if you're using `long` to account for the sign bit. I think you can get 64 if you're using `ulong`.

Example:

```
[Flags]
enum Signals : long
{
   None = 0,
   LONGPULLBACK = 1,
   SHORTPULLBACK = 2,
   RSIOVERSOLD = 4,
   RSIOVERBOUGHT = 8,
   //etc.
};
```

(I'll add that what you were trying to do would work if you were multiplying the numbers. But that would make the number pretty big. Also, [decomposition wouldn't be as simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873129/939213).)

Comment: I suspect you didn't mean `LONGPULLBACK` to be `0`.

Comment: nope. now fixed it as follows
[Flags]
  enum Signals : long
        {
            NONE=0,
   LONGPULLBACK = 2,
            SHORTPULLBACK = 4,
            RSIOVERSOLD = 8,
            RSIOVERBOUGHT = 16,
            BOUGHTSIGNAL = 32,
            DOUBLEBOUGHTSIGNAL = 64,
            SOLDSIGNAL = 128,
            DOUBLESOLDSIGNAL = 256,
            MATRENDINGLONG = 512,
            MATRADENINGSHORT = 1024


        };

Comment: @junkone You can also write 1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2, and so on, so you don’t need to calculate the numbers yourself. Also I think it makes it much clearer which enum member is expressed by which bit.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the correction. Edited now.