# Picking A, C and M for Linear congruential generator

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, prng, number-theory

I am looking to implement a simple [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG) that has a specified period and guaranteed no collisions for the duration of that period. After doing some research I came across the very famous [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which is perfect. The problem is, I am having trouble understanding how to properly configure it. Here is my current implementation:

```
    function LCG (state)
    {
        var a = ?;
        var c = ?;
        var m = ?;

        return (a * state + c) % m;
    }
```

It says that in order to have a full period for all seed values the following conditions must be met:

1. **c** and **m** are relatively prime
2. **a-1** is divisible by all prime factors of **m**
3. **a-1** is a multiple of 4 if **m** is a multiple of 4

**1** and **3** are simple to understand and test for. However what about **2**, I don't quite understand what that means or how to check for it. And what about C, can it be zero? what if it's non-zero?

*Overall I need to select A, C and M in such a way that I have a period of **48^5 - 1**. M is equal to the period, I am not sure about A and C.*

Comment: `c` must not be zero. If it were, there would be a trivial loop when `state=0`.

Comment: ACM?  I see what you did there...  http://www.acm.org/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Provided that *c* is nonzero, the LCG will have a full period for all seed values if and only if:
>
> 1. *c* and *m* are relatively prime,
> 2. *a*-1 is divisible by all prime factors of *m*,
> 3. *a*-1 is a multiple of 4 if *m* is a multiple of 4.

You said you want a period of 48<sup>5</sup>-1, so you must choose *m*≥48<sup>5</sup>-1. Let's try choosing *m*=48<sup>5</sup>-1 and see where that takes us. The conditions from the Wikipedia article prohibit you from choosing *c*=0 if you want the period to be *m*.

Note that 11, 47, 541, and 911 are the prime factors of 48<sup>5</sup>-1, since they're all prime and 11*47*541*911 = 48<sup>5</sup>-1.

Let's go through each of those conditions:

1. For *c* and *m* to be relatively prime, *c* and *m* must have no common prime factors. So, pick any prime numbers *other than* 11, 47, 541, and 911, then multiply them together to choose your *c*.
2. You'll need to choose *a* such that *a*-1 is divisible by all the prime factors of *m*, i.e., *a* = *x**11*47*541*911 + 1 for any *x* of your choosing.
3. Your *m* is not a multiple of 4, so you can ignore the third condition.

**In summary:**

- m = 48<sup>5</sup>-1,
- c = any product of primes other than 11, 47, 541, and 911 (also, *c* must be less than *m*),
- a = *x**11*47*541*911 + 1, for any nonnegative *x* of your choice (also, *a* must be less than *m*).

---

Here's a smaller test case (in Python) using a period of 48<sup>2</sup>-1 (which has prime factors 7 and 47):

```
def lcg(state):
    x = 1
    a = x*7*47 + 1
    c = 100
    m = 48**2 - 1
    return (a * state + c) % m

expected_period = 48**2 - 1
seeds = [5]
for i in range(expected_period):
    seeds.append(lcg(seeds[-1]))
print(len(set(seeds)) == expected_period)
```

It outputs `True`, as it should. (If you have any trouble reading Python, let me know and I can translate it to JavaScript.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous answer is inappropriate in suggesting that one choose m=48^5-1, since the resulting definition of a is larger than m which
is, according to Wikipedia, inappropriate.

Comment: @MPT: You still get a period of *m* if you set *x* = 0 (i.e., *a* = 1). The resulting numbers won't be very random, though :)

Comment: You write `m = 48^5-1` and `a = x*11*47*541*911 + 1, [...] (also, a must be less than m)`. Now `11*47*541*911` is precisely `m`, so this second statement is equivalent to `a = x*m + 1, [...] (also, a must be less than m)`. Assuming `x != 0`, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clément: I'm not assuming *x* ≠ 0, just that it is nonnegative. However, as noted in my previous comment, *x* = 0 isn't a very good choice. (A better idea would be to look at *m* > 48^5-1.)

Comment: Indeed, hence my comment: writing `for any nonnegative x of your choice` feels misleading when the only x that actually satisfies the conditions that you state is `x = 0`. Using a larger m would indeed be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Snowball's answer and the comments I've created a complete example. You can use the `set == list` comparison for smaller numbers. I could not fit `48^5-1` into memory.

To circumvent the `a < m` problem, I'm incrementing the target a few times to find a number where `a` is able to be `< m` (where `m` has duplicated prime factors). Surprisingly +2 is enough for a lot of numbers. The few extra numbers are later skipped while iterating.

```
import random

def __prime_factors(n):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/412942/6078370
    Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer
    """
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n //= d
        d += 1
        if d * d > n:
            if n > 1: factors.append(n)
            break
    return factors

def __multiply_numbers(numbers):
    """multiply all numbers in array"""
    result = 1
    for n in numbers:
        result *= n
    return result

def __next_good_number(start):
    """
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#c%E2%89%A00
    some conditions apply for good/easy rotation
    """
    number = start
    factors = __prime_factors(number)
    while len(set(factors)) == len(factors) or number % 4 == 0:
        number += 1
        factors = __prime_factors(number)
    return number, set(factors)

# primes < 100 for coprime calculation. add more if your target is large
PRIMES = set([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
        43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97])

def create_new_seed(target):
    """be aware, m might become > target"""
    m, factors = __next_good_number(target)
    a = __multiply_numbers(factors) + 1
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers
    otherPrimes = [p for p in PRIMES if p not in factors]
    # the actual random part to get differnt results
    random.shuffle(otherPrimes)
    # I just used arbitary 3 of the other primes
    c = __multiply_numbers(otherPrimes[:3])
    # first number
    state = random.randint(0, target-1)
    return state, m, a, c

def next_number(state, m, a ,c, limit):
    newState = (a * state + c) % m
    # skip out of range (__next_good_number increases original target)
    while newState >= limit:
        newState = (a * newState + c) % m

    return newState

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target = 48**5-1
    state, m, a, c = create_new_seed(target)
    print(state, m, a, c, 'target', target)

    # list and set can't fit into 16GB of memory
    checkSum = sum(range(target))
    randomSum = 0
    for i in range(target):
        state = newState = next_number(state, m, a ,c, target)
        randomSum += newState
    print(checkSum == randomSum) # true
```

LCG is quite fascinating and usable in things like games.
You can iterate a giant list of things in a deterministic random order. Shuffeling and saving the whole list is not required:

```
def riter(alist):
    """ iterate list using LCG """
    target = len(alist)
    state, m, a, c = create_new_seed(target)
    for _ in range(target):
        yield alist[state]
        state = next_number(state, m, a ,c, target)
```

It is easy to save the state in between iteration steps:

```
savedState = '18:19:25:6:12047269:20'
print('loading:', savedState)
i, state, m, a, c, target = (int(i) for i in savedState.split(':'))
state = next_number(state, m, a, c, target)
i += 1
print('i:', i, 'is random number:', state, 'list done:', i+1 == target)
print('saving:', '{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(i, state, m, a, c, target))
```