# Linear congruential generator

Tags: python, random, lcg

i want to check whether the selected parameters, a, c and m, will generate full period random number or not. i want to write the code for it. I wrote the code for it but it does not work correctly.
the code is

```
def gcd(small, large):
    if(large < small):
      temp = large
      large = small
      small = temp

    for i in range(small, 0, -1):
        
        if large % i == 0 and small % i == 0:
            return i

# m and c must be co-prime
def relative_prime_condition(c, m):
    if gcd(c,m) == 1:
        return True
    return False

def is_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(number/2) + 1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
    
# a-1 must divide all the prime factors of m
def prime_factor_condition(a, m):
    for i in range(2, int(m/2) + 1):
        if is_prime(i) and m % i == 0 and (a-1) % i != 0:
            return False
    return True

# if m divides 4, then a-1 must divide 4    
def num4_condition(a, m):
    if m % 4 == 0 and (a-1) % 4 != 0:
        return False
    return True
    
def LCG(seed, a, c, m):
    random_numbers = [seed]
    
    if relative_prime_condition(c,m) and prime_factor_condition(a,m) and num4_condition(c,m):
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            random_numbers.append((a * random_numbers[i-1] + c) % m)
    
    else:
        print("These Parameters are not able to generate the random numbers")
        for i in range(1, 5):
            random_numbers.append((a * random_numbers[i-1] + c) % m)
    
    return random_numbers

print(LCG(seed=0, a=5, c=3, m=13))
```

this code displays
[0, 3, 5, 2, 0, 3, 5, 2, 0, 3, 5, 2, 0, 3]

all three conditions are satisfied but don't know why it is not generating full period random numbers.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @chepner For `m == 13`, a full cycle generator will produce a permutation of every value between 0 and 12, inclusive, followed by exactly the same sequence repeated. In other words, each of the first 13 values should be distinct, the 14th value should equal the first, the 15th should equal the second, the 16th should equal the third, and so on. Since that didn’t happen, the chosen parameters don’t yield a full cycle generator.

Comment: Swapping values is easier in python: to swap the values in `a` and `b`, just do `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Picking A, C and M for Linear congruential generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096294/picking-a-c-and-m-for-linear-congruential-generator)

Answer (score 2):

The [Hull-Dobell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length) specifies three cases in which specific sub-conditions result in a maximal cycle LCG.

- m == prime, c == 0
- m == power of 2, c == 0
- m == power of 2, c ≠ 0

Your parameters don’t qualify for any of the three, since you have a non-zero value of `c` — excluding cases 1 and 2 — but `m` is not a power of 2, so you don’t match case 3 either.

Comment: There are more conditions for that theorem involving the multiplier `a`. Furthermore, with c==0 and m a power of 2, the largest possible cycle is m/4.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk That’s why I mentioned sub-conditions. Didn’t go into them because OP failed to meet any of the primary categorizations.