# prime factor python nightmare

Tags: python, numbers, generator

I've been trying to get python to find the highest prime factor of a number and, 11 days of banging my obviously dumb head later, I'm ready to ask for help.

Any idea why this won't return the highest prime factor? It either takes so long I quit the program manually, or complains that `python int to large to convert to C long`.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

```
def primeCheck(value):
    for x in range(2, int(value / 2) + 1):
        if value % x < 0.1:
            return False
    return True

val = int(raw_input('What number would you like the highest prime factor of?'))
pc = 2
for x in xrange(pc, int((val / pc) + 1)):
    if primeCheck(x) and val % x < 0.1:
        val = val / x
        pc = x
print pc
```

Comment: The fact that it takes a while for large numbers is owed to the fact that your algorithm design takes O(n^2) time. You have two nested loop essentially searching the range (1..n). This takes increasingly more time with bigger input values.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, as I was just reading a lovely solution to this today - here you go:

**[Tryptych's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412942/1179880)**

```
def prime_factors(n):
    "Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while (n > 1):
        while (n%d==0):
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1

    return factors


pfs = prime_factors(1000)
largest_prime_factor = pfs[-1] # The largest (last) element in the prime factor array
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primality test could be much better. Depending on how large the numbers you need to test are, you could just maintain a huge set of them. This is a [nice collection of primes](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/). Better would be a proper test like Miller-Rabin, see [my code](https://gist.github.com/sharnett/5479106) for a deterministic version that works up to a very large limit.

You could also look at real [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I made. It finds the number of primes from 2 to a large number. it then writes the primes to a textfile.

```
import math
length = 1
percentage = 1
startNumber = input('What number would you like to start counting from? (This has to be 2 to work)')
endNumber = input('What number would you like to finish counting to?')
file = open('Primes.txt','r+')
print(2)
for num in range(int(startNumber) + 1,int(endNumber) + 1,2):
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1)):
        print(num)
        file.write(str(num) + '\n')
        length += 1
print('There are ' + str(length) + ' primes between ' + str(startNumber) + ' and ' + str(endNumber) + '.')
file.close()
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

First I define a function which returns True if a number is prime number.

```
def prime(i):
""" This function finds whether a number is prime or not?"""
val=False
for n in range(2,i):
    if i%n==0:
            break;
else:
    val=True
return val
```

Then I use this function to find the prime factors of the input number.

```
for x in range(2,num):
if num%x==0: 
    if prime(x)==True:
        print ("prime factor of {} is {}".format(num,x))
```

num being the input number.