# Euler 3 Solution, Why?

Tags: python

I am beginner here, this code should work theoretically, cheers to you awesome guys for helping me out !

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Euler problem 3

## Euler problem 3

```
    def prime(n):
             for i in range(2,n-1):
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

         x = input("Enter a number plz")
         d = 0
         while x > 0:
         d = d + 1
         if x % d == 0:
          if prime(d) is True:
            print d
```

Comment: And the problem is? (please describe in detail what it is that you expect to see and what it is that you are actually seeing)

Comment: The problem is that your code is super slow. Find a way to reduce the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to a similar question:
[Largest prime factor of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287/prime-factors)

And a better solution:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1

    return factors


pfs = prime_factors(600851475143)
largest_prime_factor = max(pfs) # The largest element in the prime factor list
print pfs 
print largest_prime_factor

#output
[71, 839, 1471, 6857]
```

6857