# Largest Prime Factor using BigInteger Class

Tags: java, prime-factoring

```
package Exercises;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger ("600851475143");
        BigInteger prime = new BigInteger ("0");

        for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2"); i.compareTo(x.divide(new BigInteger("2"))) < 1; i = i.add(new BigInteger("1")))
        {
            if (x.mod(i) == new BigInteger ("0"))
                if (isPrime(i))
                    prime = i;
        }
        System.out.println(prime);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime (BigInteger number)
    {
        for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2"); i.compareTo(number.divide(new BigInteger("2"))) < 1; i = i.add(new BigInteger("1")))
        {
            if (number.mod(i) == new BigInteger("0"))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

so I'm trying to find the largest prime factor for 600851475143 but when i run it it doesn't display anything and it keeps running how can i fix this ?

Comment: Well, for starters you could use a more efficient prime check.

Comment: Do you need to find the largest prime factor of a specific number (`600851475143`) or your input is not constant?

Comment: For this number

Comment: Have you tested it with some lower numbers (`< 100`) where you know the correct result and can thus *confirm* that your algorithm even works, in general?

Comment: @Zabuza nope gonna do this in the morning

Comment: This algorithm need to be optimized, it takes really a long time. You can refer to the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287/largest-prime-factor-of-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug here.
`if (x.mod(i) == new BigInteger ("0"))`
suppose `x=2, i=2`, then `x%i=0`, but here will return a `false`, due to `==` will compare the address of the variable not the value.`equals` is a preferred one.

---

As @Zabuza suggested, I found a resource about the [difference between == and equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java).

Comment: You could improve the answer by adding a ressource that explains the difference between `equals` and `==`, for example another SO question with good answers, if you like.

Comment: Also, you can print a debug message in the first for loop `System.out.println("DEBUG " + i);`

Comment: @Zabuza What is SO short for?

Comment: **SO** stands for **StackOverflow**, so the site we are currently at :)